# Generate n-gram from a large corpus

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp, nltk, gensim, n-gram

I am using the wikipidia corpus (17G) and python language to obtain a n-gram model. I've used `sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer` but it does not has any progress bar or verbose option. Is there a recommended way?

Comment: Do you seek advice on how to create the output of sklearn's `CountVectorizer` using another library (because it takes too long), or to display the progress of sklearn's `CountVectorizer` ?

Comment: You should show your code & better-explain what your goals are. (Is it just impatience being unsure what `CountVectorizer` is doing, or something else?)

Comment: I want to ensure `CountVectorizer` will not cost a week to complete the corpus.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. The solution is simple. Edit the source code since the code is easy to follow. Add tqdm to the for loop.